# What causes "WTContextManager() this:..." to be output in the console?

Tags: windows-7, qt-creator

For some time I observe the following behaviour in Qt Creator. Each time I run an application, I get similar messages in the console:

```
WTContextManager() this:e9ed0340
WTRoundArray() this:e9ed0bc0

...

~WTRoundArray() this:e9ed0bc0
~WTContextManager() this:e9ed0340
```

This is not a warning nor an error, but just a text, and it happens regardless of the code I have written.

What are the `WTContextManager` and `WTRoundArray` classes and why they cause such output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a rare behavior. It is caused by the HUION Drawing Tablet drivers, as described [here](https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/issues/664).

Removing the drivers removes the text.

However, since it does not influence the applications in a bad way, I do not think it should be of any consideration.